How to aggregate by date using Teradata Period data type?
I am creating a status history table for our equipment. These statuses are updated as the equipment move from one status to another. The goal is to get the number of equipment hours by status for every day till the current date. It can be assumed that there are no overlapping periods of status for an individual unit.
I am looking to use Teradata's Period data type to store the statuses because it seems to has some other built in functionality that will be useful. However, I cannot seem to find a way to aggregate in the way described above.
Say I have the following table:
CREATE SET TABLE STATUS(
    ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    STATUS VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    DURATION PERIOD(TIMESTAMP(0)) NOT NULL
)
PRIMARY INDEX(EQ_INIT_NR, STATUS, DURATION);

With the following data:
INSERT INTO STATUS VALUES ('A1', 'ACTIVE', PERIOD(TIMESTAMP'2024-01-01 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP'2024-01-02 00:00:00'));
INSERT INTO STATUS VALUES ('A1', 'IDLE', PERIOD(TIMESTAMP '2024-01-02 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP'2024-01-03 00:00:00'));
INSERT INTO STATUS VALUES ('A1', 'ACTIVE', PERIOD(TIMESTAMP '2024-01-03 00:00:00', UNTIL_CHANGED));


INSERT INTO STATUS VALUES ('B2', 'ACTIVE', PERIOD(TIMESTAMP'2024-01-01 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP'2024-01-02 00:00:00'));
INSERT INTO STATUS VALUES ('B2', 'IDLE', PERIOD(TIMESTAMP '2024-01-02 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP'2024-01-02 12:00:00'));
INSERT INTO STATUS VALUES ('B2', 'ACTIVE', PERIOD(TIMESTAMP '2024-01-02 12:00:00', UNTIL_CHANGED));

How can I aggregate using the status column and date to give the number of hours per status per day?
The following is what I am expecting:
| DATE       | STATUS   |  DURATION |
| --------   | -------- | --------- |
| 2024-01-01 | ACTIVE   |    48     |
| 2024-01-01 | IDLE     |    0      |
| 2024-01-02 | ACTIVE   |    12     |
| 2024-01-02 | IDLE     |    36     |
| 2024-01-03 | ACTIVE   |    48     |
| 2024-01-03 | IDLE     |    0      |
| 2024-01-04 | ACTIVE   |    48     |
| 2024-01-04 | IDLE     |    0      |
|     ...    |    ...   |    ...    |
| CURRENT_DT | ACTIVE   |    48     |
| CURRENT_DT | IDLE     |    00     |

2024-01-01 has 48 hours for ACTIVE since A1 and B2 are active during the entire day.
2024-01-02 has 12 hours for ACTIVE since B2 was active for only half the day and 36 hours were idle because A1 was idle for the entire day and B2 was idle for the other half.
2024-01-03 has 48 hours for active since both units were ACTIVE during the entire day.
This last status should cascade till the current date until the status is changed (2024-01-04 to CURRENT_DT).

This teradata community post does a good job of explaining Period function examples, but none of them quite seem to fit the requirements above.

@Andrew I may be misunderstanding your comment. The table does have IDLE at 36 hours for 2024-01-02. ACTIVE is at 12 hours for that day.

Sorry, apparently reading is difficult today...
